# Having trouble going to the next row

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing data onto a table that I am building, but my data keeps on "writing over" the previous data and won't start a new row instead. I have this built so far.

Edit: I added more of my code to show where it is looping. Still unsure why it is not looping still, but here's what I have.

```
                For Each cel In Range("K2:K" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                
                'Now we need to verify if the date from the for loop falls
                'between our inputed start and end date
                DeliverableDate = cel
                If ((DeliverableDate >= Start_Date) And (DeliverableDate <= End_Date)) Then
                    'This "if" statement states that we have found a value between the deliverable dates
                    'Next let's record the work order associated for this project
                    
                    'We can achieve this by using the index/match commands
                    'Start by establishing the last rows for the work orders and and the deliverables
                    
                     Dim WorkOrderDeliverableDatelastRow As Long
                     WorkOrderDeliverableDatelastRow = .Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                     
                     Dim DeliverableDatelastRow As Long
                     DeliverableDatelastRow = .Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                     
                     'Set the ranges for these values
                                              
                      Set WorkOrderRange = .Range("E2:E" & WorkOrderDeliverableDatelastRow)
                      Set DeliverableDateRange = .Range("K2:K" & DeliverableDatelastRow)
                      Dim workOrder As String
                      
                      workOrder = Application.Index(WorkOrderRange, Application.Match(cel, DeliverableDateRange, 0))
                      
                      'Let's write back onto our workbook onto out dashboard
                      
                      ScheduleOverview.Activate
                                              
                      
                      'Let's first established where we want to write this on our dashboard.
                      
                      
                      With ScheduleOverview
                      
                        'Now we need to state where we want the first lines of deliverable to start
                      
                        Dim Row As Long
                        Dim WorkOrderColumn As Integer
                        Dim DeliverableDatesColumn As Integer
                      
                        Row = 17
                        WorkOrderColumn = 5
                        DeliverableActivityColumn = 12
                        DeliverableDatesColumn = 13
                        
                        
                        Debug.Print workOrder
                        
                        Cells(Row, WorkOrderColumn).Value = workOrder
                        Cells(Row, DeliverableActivityColumn).Value = DeliverableCodes
                        Cells(Row, DeliverableDatesColumn).Value = DeliverableDate
                        
                        'Go to next row
                        Row = Row + 1
                      
                      End With
                        
                        
                      
                      TVADeliverablesSpreadsheet.Activate
                    
                      
                Else
                End If
              
            Next cel
```

Comment: There is no loop in your code, so it's going to start at 17 each time. Is part of the code missing? Maybe you aren't trying to loop? Still, part of your code is missing so it's difficult to know what exactly is causing this code to run in the first place.

Comment: Now that you have added some code for the loop, put the `Row = 17` before you start the loop instead of inside the loop (where it is now). I am not sure it's going to do exactly what you want then, but at least it will not start at 17 every time.

Comment: Hey that worked! Thanks for your help!